# Copy Task after Linking

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to perform a copy of the build artifacts after performing the linking for Native Executables. Attached is an excerpt from my `build.gradle`

```
    components {
        all {
            binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinarySpec) {
                buildable = false 
            }
            binaries.withType(NativeExecutableBinarySpec) {
                tasks.withType(LinkExecutable) {        
                    doFirst {
                        outputFile = file("$buildDir/exe/${baseName}/${baseName}.o")
                    }
                    doLast {
                        copy {
                            from (file("$buildDir/exe/${baseName}/"))
                            into "./objs_exe/exe/"
                            include "*.o"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to rename my linked executable and then copy it to another location. However, I get the error as

> Attempt to modify a closed view of model element 'components' of type 'ComponentSpecContainer' given to rule model.components

This is a multi-project build and the above code is part of the root project's `build.gradle`. The `doFirst` closure works without any issues. Also, I have applied the `c plugin`